# Applied Divergence Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I'm struggling immensely with this problem, I can't seem to evaluate and use the Divergence Theorem correctly.  I've approached this problem in both spherical and cylindrical coordinates and can't solve it.  The problem states;

A non-zero scalar field $\psi$ is such that $||\vec{\nabla}\psi||^2$ = 3$\psi$ and $\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\psi\vec{\nabla}\psi)$ = 10$\psi$.  Evaluate $$\iint_{S}\vec{\nabla}\psi \cdot \hat{n}dS$$ when S is the surface of the region in the first octant bounded by z = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, z = $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, y = x and y = $\sqrt{3}x$.  Also we are required to solve this problem using $\underline{both}$ spherical and cylindrical coordinates.

Any guidance and advice would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote down the integral correctly? It seems like the information given about $\psi$ is not useful at all.

Comment: @CheeHan Please see my "HINT" in the posted solution.

Comment: @Dr.MV I wrote down exactly the same thing, but it doesn't correspond to the integral at all since if you were to apply Divergence theorem, you get the integral over $D$ of the Laplacian of $\psi$. (Ahhhhhh I see, nvm, good catch!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using the product rule for the divergence, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \left(\psi \nabla \psi\right)&=\psi \nabla ^2(\phi)+\nabla (\psi)\cdot \nabla (\psi)\\\\
&=\psi \nabla ^2(\phi)+\left|\nabla (\psi)\right|^2 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.

> Solving $(1)$ for $\nabla^2(\psi)$, we find that $$\nabla^2(\psi)=\frac{\nabla \cdot (\psi \nabla (\psi))-\left|\nabla (\psi)\right|^2}{\psi}=7$$Using the Divergence Theorem, the result is $7\times \,\,\text{Volume enclosed}$.

Now, solve for $\nabla^2 \cdot (\psi)$, apply the given relationships, and integrate a constant over the volume of interest.

Comment: Sorry I asked such a stupid question, good hint (:

Comment: @CheeHan Thank you!  Much appreciated.  -Mark

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. MV!  However after I have the Laplacian of $\psi$ = 7 how would I proceed to implementing the Divergence Theorem and evaluating the triple integral with the integrand div($\psi$) over the volume of interest? I'm just not seeing it :(

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The divergence of the gradient is the Laplacian.  And the Laplacian is $7$.  Now integrate $7$ over the volume of interest.

Comment: Oh my, I just realized what I was misinterpreting.  Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and your patience!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.